# How to remove newlines from a text file with batch or PowerShell

Tags: string, powershell, batch-file, file-io, cmd

Essentially, I want to read from file.txt with contents

```
apple
banana
carrot
```

and write to newfile.txt so that it will have contents

```
apple banana carrot
```

I need to do this on a Windows computer on which I do not have install permissions.

I tried

```
set row=
for /f %%x in (file.txt) do set row=%row% %%x
echo row > newfile.txt
```

and I tried using PowerShell statements (I cannot run PowerShell scripts) instead of the CMD-style `for` loop.

```
powershell -Command "(Gc file.txt) | Foreach-Object -Process {set row=%row% _$} | Out-File newFile.txt"
```

but both produce an empty file. 
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Well, the first doesn't work because you set row to an empty value, never assign `%%x` to `row` (which leaves row empty), and then you write the empty row to the file. What do you think the `for %%x in` means?

Comment: `findstr /v "^$" File1.txt > File2.txt`

Comment: I thought it was each line in the file.

Comment: @ACatInLove That would just remove blank lines from the input, which from my understanding is not what the OP wants.

Comment: It is, but then you ignore the line (don't use it at all). Again, what do you think the `%%x` in `for %%x in` means?  `%%x` is the *each line*, so you have to use the contents of the line. Your attempt does not do so.

Comment: thanks. I noticed that typo. I changed it to do set row=%row% %%x and ran it but I still get an empty file.

Comment: `(for /f %%x in (file.txt) do set /P "=%%x ") < nul > newfile.txt`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Get-Content` returns the content of a file as an array of lines with the line breaks already removed, so all you need to do (in PowerShell) is to join the lines and write the result back to a file:

```bsh
(Get-Content 'input.txt') -join ' ' | Set-Content 'output.txt'
```

---

Not recommended, but if you must do this in batch you need something like this:

```batch
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set row=
for /f %%x in (file.txt) do set "row=!row! %%x"
>newfile.txt echo %row%
```

Note that delayed expansion is *required* for this to work. Without it `%row%` in the loop body would be expanded at parse time (when the variable is still empty), so you'll end up with just the last line from the input file in the variable after the loop completes. With delayed expansion enabled (and using `!row!` instead of `%row%`) the variable is expanded at run time, i.e. during the loop iterations as one would normally expect.

For further information on delayed expansion see [Raymond Chen's blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060823-00/?p=29993/).

Comment: Batch solution will only work if text file size is less than 8192 because [environment variables are restricted to max. 8191 characters](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/830473/command-prompt-cmd--exe-command-line-string-limitation).

Answer (score 3):

To *complement* [Ansgar Wiechers' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47999629/45375):

Executing the following command from a batch file / a `cmd.exe` console window should do what you want:

```
powershell -command "\"$(Get-Content file.txt)\" > newFile.txt"
```

- Note the escaping of embedded `"` as `\"`, which PowerShell requires when called *from the outside* (by contrast, PowerShell-*internally*, `` ` `` is the escape character).
- Enclosing the `Get-Content file.txt` call - which outputs an *array* of lines - in a *double-quoted string*, using *subexpression operator* `$(...)`, means that the array elements are *implicitly* joined with a space each.

Note, however, that PowerShell's output-redirection operator, `>`, creates UTF16-LE ("Unicode") encoded files by default, as does `Out-File` (at least in *Windows* PowerShell; the cross-platform PowerShell *Core* defaults to (BOM-less) UTF-8).

To control the output encoding, use the `-Encoding` parameter, which you can apply to `Out-File` or, preferably - knowing that *strings* are being output - `Set-Content`.

In Windows PowerShell, note that `Set-Content` - in contrast with `>` / `Out-File` - defaults to the encoding implied by the legacy "ANSI" code page, typically Windows-1252.