# Run multiple commands and log output as one row on Windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

i am trying to run a command 1 (wmic diskdrive get status) and command 2(wmic OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE) and write output as one row to a file.

**background information**
*I need to monitor SMART status with zabbix agent active. Windows version is one without powershell and i have very limited user rights there. I have about 50 machines that i need to monitor with it and a .bat skript is the most viable solution i have*

**background information ends**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion


set "INTEXTFILE=c:\zabbix\smart_log.txt"
set "OUTTEXTFILE=c:\zabbix\smart_log_out.txt"
(wmic diskdrive get status 
wmic OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE) 1> %INTEXTFILE%
```

so far so good. I get a *smart_log.txt* with information:

```
Status  
OK      


LocalDateTime=20200114155453.199000+120
```

From here on i try to edit this file, to get all of this data as one row, but here i run into trouble. 
i tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999562/how-to-remove-newlines-from-a-text-file-with-batch-or-powershell) but no luck.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set row=
for /f %%x in (%INTEXTFILE%) do set "row=!row! %%x"
>%OUTTEXTFILE% echo %row%
```

All i get there is :

```
ECHO is off.
```

My goal is to get a file with row:

```
Status OK (*maybe multiple OK OK OK if there are many disks)  LocalDateTime=20200114155453.199000+120
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "line="
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic diskdrive get status^|more') do set "line=!line!%%a,"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS GET LocalDateTime /value ^| more') do set  line=!line!%%a
set "line=%line: =%"
echo %line:,= %
```

The output of `wmic` as an usual line ending (CRCRLF instead of `CRLF`) which complicates things. Piping it to `more` "corrects" those line endings. Then just concatenate the lines. To beautify (and adapt to your required format) build the strings with another delimiter (comma here),remove any spaces, and change the commas back to spaces.

Output on my system:

```
Status OK OK OK  LocalDateTime=20200114165152.456000+060
```

Hint: changing to `delims=.` for the second `for` loop (the date), changes the output to:

```
Status OK OK OK  LocalDateTime=20200114165555
```

Comment: Hint: changing to `%%~na` for the second for loop (the date), should change the output similarly, _(`set  line=!line!%%~na`)_.

Comment: Super. Thank you for the quick and perfect reply.